# How do I inject a class that uses androidContext in an instrumented test with Koin?

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

One of my classes has a dependency of type Context. Before adding Koin to my project, I initialized this with a hard dependency on my Application class:

```
class ProfileRepository(
    private var _context: Context? = null,
    private var _profileRestService: IProfileRestService? = null
) : IProfileRepository {

    init {
        if (_context == null) {
            _context = MyApplication.getInstance().applicationContext
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to use Koin to inject this dependency. This is how I've defined the module:

```
object AppModule {

    @JvmField
    val appModule = module {
        single<IProfileRestService> { ProfileRestService() }
        single<IProfileRepository> { ProfileRepository(androidContext(), get()) }
    }
}
```

I'm starting Koin in the `onCreate` method of my Application class (which is written in Java):

```
startKoin(singletonList(AppModule.appModule));
```

I want to test this class with an instrumented test and not a unit test because I want to use the real context and not a mock. This is my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    private val _profileRepository by inject<IProfileRepository>()

    @Test
    fun testSomething() {
        assertNotNull(_profileRepository)
    }
```

The test is failing with an exception:

```
org.koin.error.BeanInstanceCreationException: Can't create definition for 'Single [name='IProfileRepository',class='com.my.app.data.profile.IProfileRepository']' due to error :
No compatible definition found. Check your module definition
```

I can get it to work with a unit test if I mock the context like so:

```
class MyTest : KoinTest {

    private val _profileRepository by inject<IProfileRepository>()

    @Before
    fun before() {
        startKoin(listOf(AppModule.appModule)) with mock(Context::class.java)
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun testSomething() {
        assertNotNull(_profileRepository)
    }
```

How can I make it work as an instrumented test with a real context?

Comment: I think this may be a bug in koin-java. See https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/352.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to start Koin from a Java class and inject the application context. What that means is if one of your classes needs to get the context from the container, you must use `org.koin.android.ext.android.startKoin` instead of `org.koin.java.standalone.KoinJavaStarter.startKoin`.

Since my Application class is still written in Java, I created an object called KoinHelper with one method:

```
@JvmStatic
fun start(application: Application) {
    application.startKoin(application, listOf(AppModule.appModule))
}
```

Then I called this from the `onCreate` method of my Application class:

```
KoinHelper.start(this);
```

Now, the instrumented test I posted in my original answer runs just fine.

Please see [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/352) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In place of (in Application):

```
startKoin(applicationContext, modules)
```

Use a mocked Context:

```
startKoin(modules) with (mock(Context::class.java))
```

From https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html#_starting_koin_with_android_context_from_elsewhere

Comment: I'm specifically trying to use a real context for an instrumented test.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://insert-koin.io/docs/1.0/documentation/koin-android/index.html#_starting_koin_with_android_context_from_elsewhere) section in the documentation. It says

> if you need to start Koin from another Android class, you can use the
>   startKoin() function and provide your Android Context instance with
>   just like:
>
> startKoin(androidContext, myAppModules)

So in your instrumentation test, you can pass a context while starting the Koin.

```
@Before
fun before() {
        startKoin(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), listOf(AppModule.appModule))
    }
```

Or if you want an application level context

```
@Before
fun before() {
        startKoin(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), listOf(AppModule.appModule))
    }
```

The referenced documentation is for Version 1.0.1

Comment: In an instrumented test, I can't call `startKoin` because it's already started in the application class. I think the problem I'm running into is actually a bug with koin-java. See https://github.com/InsertKoinIO/koin/issues/352.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of getting the `Application` context in the instrumented test, you can use `androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider`  or `InstrumentationRegistry.targetContext.applicationContext`.

```
  @Before
  fun setUp() {
    stopKoin()
    loadKoinModules(testModule) with ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Application>()
  }
```

...where `testModule` uses `androidApplication()` to retrieve the `Application` context:

```
val testModule = module {
  single {
    ToDoDatabase.newInstance(
      androidApplication(),
      memoryOnly = true
    )
  }
  single { ToDoRepository(get()) }
}
```

Note that my `stopKoin()` call is there because I was having difficulty overriding an existing module created by `startKoin()` in my custom `Application` subclass. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: This may have worked but I went with another solution, which I'll post.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    stopKoin()
    startKoin {
        androidContext(app) // for example ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<TestApplication>()
        modules(module1, module2)
    }
}
```